# Speed up reprojecting large raster (38 GB) in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, gdalwarp

I'm fairly new to QGIS and Python but nevertheless want to reproject a 38GB-DEM to a custom CRS. (The output file is supposed to be 55GB large - don't know why, but if I don't have >55GB of free disk space it won't start.)
If I use the GUI of QGIS 3.4 , I can only check the progress by right-clicking the new file and checking the size every now and then. Problem is, it slowly increases by 500MB to 1GB but then completely stops for 10-20 Minutes before increasing again. Any idea why that could be?

I've tried the Python way using the gdal code from the GUI:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
+datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
-r bilinear -of GTiff E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa.tif 
E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa_reproj.tif
```

That didn't even start:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 1
    gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -r bilinear -of GTiff E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa.tif E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa_reproj.tif
                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've read that gdalwarp does not use all CPU-cores, so maybe I could implement something like the code below, but first I would have to get gdalwarp started from the console...

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
+datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
-r bilinear -of GTiff E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa.tif 
E:/Data/03_DEM/ALOS/HMA_alos-jaxa_reproj.tif 
-multi -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS 
-oo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -doo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS
```

What are these errors? Is there another way to speed up the process? I have to do this a few times and it would be very unfortunate if it always took several days to finish...

Comment: Are you sure the reprojection is necessary? Or, if it is necessary, would a subset of the data suffice? Or could you split the data?

Comment: Yeah, I think, the reprojection is necessary to minimize the artifacts in my data. Subsetting is also not an option. I dont know if splitting, reprojecting and merging really would be faster...

Comment: Reprojection can rotate the frame of the image up to 45  degrees (which would double the image dimensions, and therefore increase storage by a factor of four). The target raster has known dimensions,  so a simple storage check is possible. Since the first few rows are mostly collar, it's not surprising that they would finish more quickly.

Comment: That makes sense. But is there a way to speed up the process or do I just have to wait?

Comment: It's not clear what interpolation model you're using, but each new pixel has to deproject the pixel centroid and read the original image at least once, and that takes time for 14.7 billion pixels.